# TP-Link AC600 driver on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS x64

Tags: drivers, wireless, iwlwifi

I tried to mt7610u on 16.04 and it worked but I can't get the WiFi to load. It just says "device not managed":

[image]

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential linux-headers-generic
git clone https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916.git
cd mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916
make
sudo make install
sudo cp RT2870STA.dat  /etc/Wireless/RT2870STA/RT2870STA.dat
```

my `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0bda:0139 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5139 Card Reader Controller
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f2:b3fd Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 13d3:3402 IMC Networks 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 1d57:ad17 Xenta 
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 007: ID 04f3:010c Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

my `rfkill list all`:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
3: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
4: phy1: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Answer (score 3):

Figured out my own answer.

edited /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
and changed managed=false to managed=true

But I don't know how to blacklist the Atheroes AR9485 internal wifi module.

Can't find it in the lsmod

```
$ sudo lsmod
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                    16384  0
ccm                    20480  0
drbg                   32768  1
ansi_cprng             16384  0
rfcomm                 69632  0
mt7610u_sta           892928  0
rtsx_usb_ms            20480  0
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_usb_ms
bnep                   20480  2
nls_iso8859_1          16384  1
asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
arc4                   16384  2
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1
intel_rapl             20480  0
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0
intel_powerclamp       16384  0
coretemp               16384  0
ath9k                 143360  0
kvm_intel             172032  0
ath9k_common           36864  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              466944  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
snd_hda_codec_realtek    81920  1
kvm                   536576  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
mac80211              737280  1 ath9k
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
aesni_intel           167936  5829
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
snd_hda_core           73728  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
cryptd                 20480  2916 aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
cfg80211              565248  5 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211,mt7610u_sta
uvcvideo               90112  0
joydev                 20480  0
input_leds             16384  0
ath3k                  20480  0
serio_raw              16384  0
btusb                  45056  0
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
btrtl                  16384  1 btusb
btbcm                  16384  1 btusb
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
btintel                16384  1 btusb
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
hid_multitouch         20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
lpc_ich                24576  0
videobuf2_v4l2         28672  1 uvcvideo
bluetooth             520192  30 bnep,ath3k,btbcm,btrtl,btusb,rfcomm,btintel
videobuf2_core         36864  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_v4l2
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_v4l2
videodev              176128  4 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core,videobuf2_v4l2
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
mei_me                 36864  0
mei                    98304  1 mei_me
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
ie31200_edac           16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
soundcore              16384  1 snd
edac_core              53248  1 ie31200_edac
mac_hid                16384  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
rtsx_usb_sdmmc         28672  0
rtsx_usb               24576  2 rtsx_usb_sdmmc,rtsx_usb_ms
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  3 hid_multitouch,hid_generic,usbhid
nouveau              1495040  1
i915                 1208320  5
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
ttm                    98304  1 nouveau
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
drm_kms_helper        139264  2 i915,nouveau
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
psmouse               126976  0
ahci                   36864  3
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
r8169                  81920  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
drm                   360448  9 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
mii                    16384  1 r8169
wmi                    20480  3 mxm_wmi,nouveau,asus_wmi
video                  40960  3 i915,nouveau,asus_wmi
fjes                   28672  0
```

Comment: Can you share your what your `NetworkManager.conf` looks like?